# Django custom template tag using session

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-sessions, django-1.8, templatetags

I have a `UpgradeView` with the same possibility for saving like in the django admin. I can *save*, *save and continue editing* or *save and create a new object*.

Each leading to a different view:

`DetailView`, `UpdateView` and the `CreateView`.

After saving I want to give a **message** out, on every view or template its leading to.
For example *"Successfully saved"* or *"Object could not be saved."*

When writing custom template tags it's getting really hard for me, because after I created the tag, I don't know how, where and when to pass the message to the other views.

This is the `UpdateView` where i come from.

```
class TopicEditView(UpdateView):
    fields = ['title','description',]
    model = Topic
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        if   self.request.POST.get('save'):
            return reverse('topic_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
        elif self.request.POST.get('save_and_continue'):
            return reverse('topic_edit', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
        elif self.request.POST.get('save_and_create_new'):
            return reverse('topic_create')
        else:
            return reverse('fallback_success_url')
```

My custom template tag is still empty, because the only examples i saw are pretty hard to understand for me.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('msg.html', takes_context=True)
def get_msg(context):
    return None
```

Inside `'msg.html'` i only have the string saying *"Successfully saved"*, this did lead to nothing and i forgot why i did that.

And this is in my template (nothing):

```
{% load msg_handler %}
{% get_msg %}
```

How and where can I **pass** the **message to** these **views using the session**?

Comment: Have you tried the messages framework?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Actually no, I don't know why I never saw that. Thanks, i will give it a try

Comment: It's awesome, give it a try. I will make an official answer of it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Django messages framework instead:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages

Answer (score 0):

I got this faster done than I ever thought.
This is my custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_msg(context):
    try:
        return context.request.session.pop('msg')
    except KeyError:
        return ''
```

And this is my view, passing the message:

```
class TopicEditView(UpdateView):
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        self.request.session['msg']='Successfully saved!'
        ...
```

Nothing have changed in my template.

If there is a more elegant/useful way, i would appreciate it.

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Lorenzo Peña's comment, i tried using the messages framework which was really easy to use!

First i went to my views.py again and imported `messages`

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

and changed this line

```
self.request.session['msg']='Successfully saved!'
```

To this:

```
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Successfully saved!')
```

Then i made a new template called msg_loader.html containing this:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
       {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

And changed in my other templates this

```
{% load msg_handler %}
{% get_msg %}
```

to this

```
{% include "msg_loader.html" %}
```